# Read From JSON File and after adding a property to that object write back to it

Tags: java, json, io, gson, apache-commons

I have an empty json file in my java project with only json object bracket:- that is

a.json

```
{}
```

i want to read from it and after adding a key value write back to it,
that is:-

```
{"a":"a"}
```

Is there any Json Library i can use to do so.

I don't wanna use simple FileReaders and FileWriters in java to read and write.

Comment: Have a look at working example here: https://howtodoinjava.com/json/json-simple-read-write-json-examples/

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743324/3060370

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several libraries for this task.

One could be Jettison https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison

```
Path filePath = <your-file-path>;
String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(filePath));
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
jsonObject.put("a", "a");
Files.write(filePath, jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
```